# Is it possible to skip some slides in the total count in R Markdown?

Tags: r-markdown, xaringan

In a presentation compiled with R Markdown and xaringan, each slide adds 1 to the cumulative slide count. However, I would like to modify this and make sure that some slides do not affect the cumulative (and total) slide count.

The preamble of the document is:

```
---
title: "my title"
author: "me myself"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    css: xaringan-themer.css
    lib_dir: libs
    nature:
      highlightStyle: github
      highlightLines: true
      countIncrementalSlides: false
      ratio: "16:9"
      beforeInit: "macros.js"
---
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `count: false` to the specific slide you do not wish to make part of the counting.

Comment: Do you have a way to also remove the appearance of the numbering in these particular slides? I'm think about the first and last slides for example.